# How do I make 2 images appear with a hover?

Tags: css, image, hover, double

Basically, I want to create a button on my web page that, when the mouse hovers over it, reveals two images, one above the other. The bottom image that appears is supposed to be an animated .gif, the second is a .gif with a word ('blog', 'music', etc.) in white and a transparent background (so that the .gif behind it can still be seen). I've tried to add the words over top of the animated .gif, but its color pallet doesn't allow white (only a light grey, which is unacceptable according to the design).

I'm pretty new to html/css, so there might be a better way to do this all together.

Comment: I remember there being something with jQuery which would make an image slide away and another image is below it, but I don't know about 2 images.

Comment: then possibly a way to display text over top of the image upon hover?

Comment: @ted.daniels Mine and my friends project http://www.photoshopmesta.net/sic/ and demo page http://www.photoshopmesta.net/sic/theTest

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a  with an  link inside of it. The css should be as follows:

```
div.background_image{
background: url('path/to_your/image.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
a.top_image:hover{
width: Xpx;
height: Xpx;
display: block;
background:transparent url('path/to_your/image.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Make the link dimensions that same size as your background image div. Should be good to go. This assumes that you want your background image div always present. The :hover is what will make the image appear on rollover

Comment: not very well it seems.

i think it's somewhere in the direction of what i need to do, but i can't get the a.classtag:hover to work.

Comment: i may have been a little over-enthusiastic in my first reply, heh.

for my purposes, i have my animated .gif appear upon hovering above the main container (of which the background is defined by #hex color instead of an image). when i looked at your code i took it that i could use the "a.class:hover" bit to add that extra image with a hover, on top of my other hover-produced image. this may be true, but i can't seem to get it to work. i used your code, but all that appears is a broken image picture in the top left.

Comment: i fixed the broken image issue, that was a fault of my code. but i still can't get an image to rollover with a:hover.

Comment: Hey ted, sorry for the delayed response. Any way you can share your code via http://jsfiddle.net/ so I can better help troubleshoot your problem?